# Is there an easier away to extract this data?

Tags: perl, extract

```
my $changelog = "/etc/webmin/Pserver_Panel/changelog.cgi";
my $Milestone;
open (PREFS, $changelog);
    while (<PREFS>)
    {
        if ($_ =~ m/^<h1>(.*)[ ]Milestone.*$/g) {
            $Milestone=$1;
            last;
        }
    }
close(PREFS);
```

> Here is an example of the data its extracting from:

```
<h1>1.77 Milestone</h1>
    <h3>    6/26/2009       </h3><ul style="margin-top:0px">
        <li type=circle>    Standard code house cleaning and added better compatbility for apache conversion.
    </ul>
    <h3>    6/21/2009       </h3><ul style="margin-top:0px">
        <li type=square>    Fixed Autofix so that it extracts to the right directory.
    </ul>
    <h3>    6/11/2009       </h3><ul style="margin-top:0px">
        <li type=circle>    Updated FTP link on index page to go to net2ftp, an online ftp file manager.
    </ul>
<h1>1.76 Milestone</h1>
    <h3>    4/14/2009       </h3><ul style="margin-top:0px">
        <li type=square>    Corrected a broken hyperlink to regular expressions in "View Chat Log"
        <li type=circle>    Changed the default number of lines back from 25 to 10 on both Chat and Pserver Logs.
        <li type=circle>    Noted in "View Pserver Log" search is case-sensitive and regular expression supported.
    </ul>
    <h3>    4/13/2009       </h3><ul style="margin-top:0px">
        <li type=disc>      Added AutoFix to the panel which will automatically fix prop errors.
        <li type=circle>    Updated error display to allow more detailed errors.
    </ul>
    <h3>    4/12/2009       </h3><ul style="margin-top:0px">
        <li type=circle>    Fixed start/stop/restart to be more reliable.
    </ul>
```

Comment: Define "easier"! This looks pretty easy to me.

Comment: Less lines of code. I guess a more complex solution is what I am really looking for that uses less lines of code. If this could be like a one-liner.

Comment: I would work towards making it better, and not worrying about the length as much.

Answer (score 4):

Next, you are going to have to parse the items between milestones. Do yourself a favor, stop worrying about lines of code and use an HTML Parser, such as [HTML::TokeParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TokeParser):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser->new( \*DATA );

while ( my $token = $parser->get_token ) {
    if ( $token->[0] eq 'S' ) {
        if ( $token->[1] eq 'h1') {
            my ($milestone) = split ' ', $parser->get_text('/h1');
            print "Milestone is '$milestone'\n";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
<h1>1.77 Milestone</h1>
...

C:\Temp> vbn
Milestone is '1.77'
Milestone is '1.76'
```

Comment: Note that this will continue to work if the lines are merged, or split up among multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

I you want a one-liner, how about this one?

```
perl -nle 'if (/^<h1>(.*)[ ]Milestone.*$/g){ print $1; last }' /etc/webmin/Pserver_Panel/changelog.cgi
```

Comment: The 'g' modifier is useless in this case, as is the trailing '.*$' part of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Another one-liner to grab it from the command line:

```
perl -ne'print $1 and exit if /<h1>(.*?)\s+Milestone/' /etc/webmin/Pserver_Panel/changelog.cgi
```